# Laravel ob-flush() clean

Tags: php, laravel

##### `Controller.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    
    public function vericek()
    {
        $name = ['testone', 'testtwo'];

        return view('urun', ['name' => $name]);
    }
}
```

##### `urun.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    $name = {{ print_r($name) }}
    </br>
    $name[0] = {{ print_r($name[0]) }}
</body>
</html>
```

##### Output:

```php
$name = Array ( [0] => testone [1] => testtwo ) 1
$name[0] = testone1
```

`1` is appended to the end of the array.

How can I resolve this issue?

Note: `ob_end_flush(); value=1`

Comment: stop echoing the return value of `print_r` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `print_r` to return a string for you to echo you would need to pass `true` as the second argument to `print_r` so it will return a string instead of printing the result (when this argument is `false` [the default value] `print_r` will print the result and return `true`):

```
{{ print_r($name, true) }}
```

Or you can not echo the return result of `print_r` and let it print it:

```
<?php print_r($name); ?>
```

[PHP.net - functions - `print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

On a side note, we also have the `dump` method available in Laravel from Symfony's VarDumper instead of `print_r` or `var_dump`:

```
dump($name)
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump) `dump`